# Deciding on a bias input

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am practicing with different network layers. Different bias inputs give different results. 
How one can find the best bias input to a DNN model? Which factors should be considered?
I have always seen linear transformations, is there a reason for this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Biases (like weight) is a parameter in the Neural Network, so it must be learned from data during training and usually you don't have to set it manually (contrary to [hyper-parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_(machine_learning))). So for parameters just try to use some good old randomly assigned values with numerical stability properties (like zero mean unit  variance).

In the other cases where you need to set precomputed biases (or weights) it will depend on the problem you are trying to learn from, so it won't be a silver bullet.

Comment: Right, One way to "support" training is to choose appropriate starting values.

Comment: "use some good old randomly assigned values with numerical stability properties" how do I do this in tensorflow?

Comment: Take a look to this https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/normal

Comment: But if you provide some code of what you are doing, more elaborate examples will arise